# Override Django Admin 'add' form template and form processing

Tags: python, django

Summary: I want to change the 'add' template in Django admin. I want to display an HTML form, which I want to processes and save some data into the database. This form and the data I'll save aren't directly rows in a model. I can override the template with `add_form_template`, but can't figure out how to use a Django Form object within that.

I have a self-referential model, where several rows may link to a single row. This linkage is to be performed by a human. For example, we might say "Select all the fruits", and list apples, oranges, bananas and cashew nuts. The next "row" of the form would say "Select all the cars", with a list of "Mini", "Jazz", "Fiesta" and "F150". We'd maybe show 10 such rows on the form, the human would select all the fruits, and cars, and do the same thing on the other 8 rows, and press submit. We'd then read the form data, and set the 'link' for all the fruits to the "All Fruit" row's ID (and same for the cars and other things).

This workflow doesn't follow the usual 'add a row' (or 'many to many') style that Django admin provides, so I'd like to override it. I've created a Proxy Model, and can replace the HTML Django shows by changing the `add_form_template` option.

I'm struggling to show a Django Form in that template though. I can't figure out how to instantiate the form object and how to have the template render it. None of the examples or hints I've found seem to work with `forms.Form` (most seem to want to use `forms.ModelForm`).

Here's my `admin.py`:

```
class MatchForm(forms.Form):
    # This is just an example until I get this working properly...
    title = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField()

class MatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # This works fine:
    add_form_template = "change_list.html"

    # This doesn't work :-(
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        defaults = {}
        if not change and not obj:
            defaults['form'] = MatchForm
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
```

I *assume* that my template could look something like this:

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

...but at the moment I can't get the `admin.py` to be happy, so haven't got that far. How can I use a custom *form* as well as a custom template in Django Admin (specifically the 'add' page)?

---

In response to comments, if there's a way I could do what I'm looking to do with a ModelForm, then that's also perfectly fine. What I can't see is how I can add form elements to a ModelForm? I can use it to make a queryset based on the "top level" elements (eg. "All Fruit", "All Cars", in the example above), but can't figure out how to present the fruits and cars within those - and then how to do "custom" form processing to work out the database updates required on the back of them.

Comment: Since you want to finally add information to the database I think you should use a `ModelForm` (even if you just include one field). To me it sounds like the perfect usecase for a `ForeignKey`. But that is not your question. I know that calling the `super().get_form(...)` will always return a modelform, since that is the default of the `get_form()` method. Try not to return the super-method and `return MatchForm()` yourself.